# Xcode Swift Unit Test Output is too verbose

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Is it possible to limit the console output of unit tests in Xcode?  I don't need to a list of every passed test case (hundreds) and test suite (dozens) listed.  I only want to see the details of what has failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...
The best solution I have found is to enter the word "failed" (without the quotes) into the filter text box at the bottom of the console window.  Once this is done the console output will show only one line for each:
 - XCTAssert failure,
 - Test case failure,
 - Test suite failure.

If there are no test failures, nothing will be displayed.  However, the "test succeeded" pop up is only displayed for a couple of seconds and if you don't see it then there is nothing to indicate that the tests have completed.

If the filter word is changed to "fail", the console output will additionally include stats for the number of tests passed or failed.  These are displayed even if all the tests pass.